# How do I send meta data fields to Stripe with Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, stripe, charge

Has anyone been able to get Carthrob to send custom meta data to Stripe? I have the 'Charge' add-on doing it perfectly but haven't managed to get Cartthrob doing it. I've tried

```
<input type="hidden" id="meta:custom-data" name="meta:custom-data" value="{segment_3}">
```

in the exp:cartthrob:checkout_form but nothing seems to be passed through. (that is basically what you use in Charge). Anyone got this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Stripe gateway for CartThrob will not look for or pass any metadata to Stripe. You'd have to manually add this into the gateway code, or roll your own custom gateway for Stripe. Consider contacting them with a feature request!

Comment: Thanks! At least I know I wasn't making some obvious mistake. Will put in a feature request.